# How to ignore compile `require` to `__webpack_require__` in webpack?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I figure out this question because I use `webpack` to bundle the code with `vm` module in it.

For example:

```
const vm = require('vm');
vm.runInNewContext(`
  const querystring = require('querystring');
  console.log(querystring.parse('foo=bar&abc=xyz&abc=123'));
`, {
  console,
  require,
});
```

this code run in node is well. when I bundle it by `webpack@1.14`. It seems like:

```
nodeVm.runInNewContext("\n 
  const querystring = require('querystring');\n\n  
  console.log(querystring.parse('foo=bar&abc=xyz&abc=123'));\n          ",{
    console: console,
    require: __webpack_require__(296)
});
```

by `webpack@2.3.2`. It seems like

```
nodeVm.runInNewContext("\n
  const querystring = require('querystring');\n\n                
  console.log(querystring.parse('foo=bar&abc=xyz&abc=123'));\n          ", {
    console: console,
    require: !(function webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module \".\""); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; }())
});
```

because the `require` changed to `__webpack_require__`, the `querystring` module in `vm` will be notFound.

Is there any ways to make webpack ignore to change the `require` to `__webpack_require__`?

Comment: Why do you use webpack if you don't want its main feature?

Comment: @zerkms the example code just some of in my project. I just want to ignore the compile here. Any suggestion?

Comment: The suggestion: if you don't want a bundler - don't use it.

Comment: You know, I really don't see the problem in wanting to keep a require as it is. Turns out that webpack has a thing exactly for that... https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__non_webpack_require__-webpack-specific

Answer (score 3):

I am sure that it works if you want to keep a require as it is, not sure if it works also in your case.

There exist the variable `__non_webpack_require__` exactly for that, follow the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-variables/#__non_webpack_require__-webpack-specific)

```js
const a = __non_webpack_require__(myvar);
```

becomes:

```js
const a = require(myvar);
```

after being compiled by webpack.